# Mapping selective data with other dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to map data( df2 & df1 ) with selective columns

```
import pandas as pd

df_data = [{'id':'1234','task':'data_trasnfer','filename':'orance_bank','date':'17-3-22'},{'id':'234','task':'data2trasnfer','filename':'ftr_data','date':'16-03-2022'},{'id':'4567','task':'data3_transfer','filename':'trnienn_data','date':'15-2-22'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
df1



    id         task        filename            date
0   1234    data_trasnfer   orance_bank     17-3-22
1   234     data2trasnfer   ftr_data       16-03-2022
2   4567    data3_transfer  trnienn_data    15-2-22


df_data1 = [{'target':'ed34','status':'sucess','flow_in':'ntfc_to_pad'},{'target':'der456','status':'error','flow_in':'htr_tokid'}]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_data1)
df2


    target  status  flow_in
0   ed34    sucess  ntfc_to_pad
1   der456  error   htr_tokid
```

expected output :

df2 data ed34 should map with only with fileaname orance_bank & der456 only map with trnienn_data

```
     id        task        filename            date       target    status  flow_in
0   1234    data_trasnfer   orance_bank     17-3-22        ed34     sucess  ntfc_to_pad
1   234     data2trasnfer   ftr_data       16-03-2022
2   4567    data3_transfer  trnienn_data    15-2-22        der456   error   htr_tokid
```

Comment: What is logic for mapping? How map another rows?

Comment: why are not mapped `ftr_data` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a mapping function, like this:

```
filemap = {
    "ed34": "orance_bank",
    "der456": "trnienn_data"
}
df2['filename'] = df2['target'].map(filemap)
```

Then merge the 2 dataframes:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='filename', how='outer').fillna('')
```